# Bash Extract specific columns from TSV file to new file and add extra column with header of extracted column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a file like this

```
name  AD01392 AV93289 AG98023 A723928
xyb323 232    3232    8992    3278
xyb897 343    434     344     3434 
xyvg87 439    3434    2434    43434
```

I need to extract the information in this file to 4 separate files that extract 
column 1 and iterate over columns 2,3 and 4 then add another column with the header of the extracted column Like so

File 1

```
name  AD01392 
xyb323 232    AD01392
xyb897 343    AD01392
xyvg87 439    AD01392
```

File 2

```
name  AV93289 
xyb323 3232   AV93289
xyb897 434    AV93289  
xyvg87 3434   AV93289
```

and so on for the other 2 files.

I can extract the columns with

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' file.tsv > file1.tsv
awk '{print $1,$3}' file.tsv > file2.tsv
awk '{print $1,$4}' file.tsv > file3.tsv
awk '{print $1,$5}' file.tsv > file5.tsv
```

but not sure how I can extract the first row from each column and add that as a column to all rows.

Thank you a lot for your help and contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==1{a[1]=$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){a[i]=$i;print a[1],a[i] > "File"++q;}next} {for(j=2;j<=NF;j++){print $1,$j,a[j] > "File"++o};o=""}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  a[1]=$1;
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    a[i]=$i;
    print a[1],a[i] > "File"++q}
  next}
{
  for(j=2;j<=NF;j++){
    print $1,$j,a[j] > "File"++o}
  o=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: I didn't know he had so many columns lol, I would have gone with a more generic approach like you did! Nice answer +1!!

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i needed!

Comment: Hi. How would i go about adding another column to this command? Say i wanted to append another column to the final output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
awk 'NR==1{save=$2;print $1,$2}NR>1{print $1,$2,save}' file.tsv > file1.tsv
awk 'NR==1{save=$3;print $1,$3}NR>1{print $1,$3,save}' file.tsv > file2.tsv
awk 'NR==1{save=$4;print $1,$4}NR>1{print $1,$4,save}' file.tsv > file3.tsv
awk 'NR==1{save=$5;print $1,$5}NR>1{print $1,$5,save}' file.tsv > file5.tsv
```

to print the last column where you just save the content of `$2`, `$3`, `$4`, `$5` in a tmp variable that you will reuse during the whole file process. By default the output field separator is space but you can change it by overwriting the content of the variable `OFS` depending on your need, so if you want for example to have `\t` as separator

```
awk 'NR==1{OFS="\t";save=$2;print $1,$2}NR>1{print $1,$2,save}' file.tsv > file1.tsv
awk 'NR==1{OFS="\t";save=$3;print $1,$3}NR>1{print $1,$3,save}' file.tsv > file2.tsv
awk 'NR==1{OFS="\t";save=$4;print $1,$4}NR>1{print $1,$4,save}' file.tsv > file3.tsv
awk 'NR==1{OFS="\t";save=$5;print $1,$5}NR>1{print $1,$5,save}' file.tsv > file5.tsv
```

**IMPROVEMENT:**

I would also recommend to use the following `awk` command in order to process the file **one and only one** time (imagine you have big file that take 2 hours to be processed)

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}NR==1{save2=$2;save3=$3;save4=$4;save5=$5;print $1,$2> "file1.tsv";print $1,$3 > "file2.tsv"; print $1,$4 > "file3.tsv"; print $1,$5 > "file5.tsv";}NR>1{print $1,$2,save2 > "file1.tsv"; print $1,$3,save3 > "file2.tsv"; print $1,$4,save4 > "file3.tsv"; print $1,$5,save5 > 
"file5.tsv";}' file.tsv
```

where the `awk` code is:

```
BEGIN{
    OFS="\t"
}

NR==1{
    save2=$2;
    save3=$3;
    save4=$4;
    save5=$5;
    print $1,$2> "file1.tsv";
    print $1,$3 > "file2.tsv";
    print $1,$4 > "file3.tsv";
    print $1,$5 > "file5.tsv";
}

NR>1{
    print $1,$2,save2 > "file1.tsv";
    print $1,$3,save3 > "file2.tsv";
    print $1,$4,save4 > "file3.tsv";
    print $1,$5,save5 > "file5.tsv";
}
```

**TESTED:**

```
$ more file?.tsv
::::::::::::::
file1.tsv
::::::::::::::
name    AD01392
xyb323  232     AD01392
xyb897  343     AD01392
xyvg87  439     AD01392
::::::::::::::
file2.tsv
::::::::::::::
name    AV93289
xyb323  3232    AV93289
xyb897  434     AV93289
xyvg87  3434    AV93289
::::::::::::::
file3.tsv
::::::::::::::
name    AG98023
xyb323  8992    AG98023
xyb897  344     AG98023
xyvg87  2434    AG98023
::::::::::::::
file5.tsv
::::::::::::::
name    A723928
xyb323  3278    A723928
xyb897  3434    A723928
xyvg87  43434   A723928
```

Comment: Thanks so much worked! Quick add on..What if I had quite a few columns to go through like for example 100 columns. Is there anyway of going about this with out do some kind of while loop with a counter?

Comment: @Ahk86: for that look at the answer from RavinderSingh13 I think he has already implemented it